# Rewriting Dynamic URLs in htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite

```
    mypage.com/country/country.php?country=something
```

to

```
    mypage.com/country/something
```

in the address bar, using htaccess

I've tried many things and looked everywhere and the closest I've got is:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} country=([^\&]*)
    RewriteRule ^country.php$ /country/%1? [R,L]
```

But this just produces a rewrite loop that alternates between the two links above and I don't understand why.

I want both

```
    mypage.com/country.php?country=something
```

and

```
    mypage.com/country/something
```

when entered, to show

```
    mypage.com/country/something
```

in the address bar

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rewrite loop it suggests that besides that rule, you also have a rule that translates it back. You'll need the 'ugly' url to only trigger when it is an external request. The easiest way to do that is by matching `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

```
#Ugly to fancy url; should be R=301 when it works
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /country\.php\?country=([^\&]*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^country.php$ /country/%2? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^country/(.*)/?$ /country.php?country=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. You have no idea how frustrating this has been. I just need to make my relative stylesheet links and images absolute now as the renaming alters the path to them and causes the page to be generated without them.

Comment: Use `<base href="http://www.example.com/">`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base